# Show Result FPC

Tags: freepascal

Hi I'm using FPC and when the code finishes without crashing it doesn't show me the end result which i need. Following is the code:

```
Program prueba1;
uses Estructu;
Var Pila1:Pila; Fila1,Completa:Fila;
Begin
    Inicfila(Completa, '');
    readpila(Pila1);
    readfila(Fila1);
    While (not pilavacia(Pila1) and not filavacia(Fila1)) do
    begin
        if (tope(Pila1) > primero(Fila1)) then
        begin
            agregar(Completa, desapilar(Pila1))
        end
        else
        if (tope(Pila1) < primero(Fila1)) then
            begin
                agregar(Completa, extraer(Fila1))
            end
            else 
            if (tope(Pila1) = primero(Fila1)) then
                begin
                    agregar(Completa, desapilar(Pila1));
                    agregar(Completa, extraer(Fila1))
                end
    end;
    writeln('La variable Completa esta compuesta de:');
    writefila(Completa)
End.
```

Additionaly what i need it to do is for the values entered into Pila1 and Fila1 to end up sorted from min to max in Completa which i know it's not doing but I don't know how to do so without using an Aux which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Do not call the code pieces (variables/functions/etc) using national language. It make the problems for somebody who don't speak on it. Use English. "it doesn't show me the end result which i need" - what it shows? what it should to show? We have no the unit `Estructu` so we can not to execute your code to test it.

Comment: Sorry this is the system with which I'm learning. What i need is for the fpc to show me the end result of all the changes made to the Complete File.

Comment: Add a line `ReadLn;` just before the final `End.`. It pauses the execution, waiting for an input like return (or `Enter`, as the key on your keyboard is named )